# Verify that apk is a paid copy (avoid piracy of app)

Tags: android, apk, android-lvl, copy-protection

I'm totally new to the Android Play store. I'm working on an app that is almost finished and ready to publish.

But I notice that you can copy the apk file (after purchase) to another location (sd card for example) and install it on another device. That is something I want to avoid.

My questions are:

- Does the Google Play store sign the apk file with some unique id before downloading? If is true, can I read/get this code from the
  apk?
- Is it possible to know the email-address of the user that purchase the app or can I access some other details of the user?
- Is it possible to get an unique detail of the device?
- Is there another solution available to protect the copy of the apk?

I want to create a registration method that binds the device to the app, so when the user tried to copy the app, it is not possible to use it. Is this all possible?

If you have any questions, let me know.

PS: I used Adobe Flash Builder to build the app.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is a combination of LVL (Android License Verification Library) and tracking device installations.

LVL
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html

Tracking Device installations
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Comment: Hai Kumar, thanks for the info. I will read it and if I have some questions I will be back.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that the user has paid there is a [Google Play Licensing service](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html), you can use it. There are copy protection mechanisms on Google Play if you choose to use them, but they are deprecated now since you are supposed to use the service I just mentioned. You can gather some unique device details, there are APIs to do that, but this is not really needed.

Comment: Hai Malcolm, thanks for the info. I will read it and if I have some questions I will be back.